# stuck while dealing with child elements on a simple html page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am pretty new at HTML, CSS and JS.

I had an idea of making a simple page titled, "an act of random kindness" where a user would simply go, type something in the box and press submit that will simply post down whatever he's just written.

To get that, I made a simple HTML page with a simple form having a "text box" and "submit button". next, I assigned two variables to the "text box" and "submit button" then with "onclick.button" property I wrote a "button handler event".

This buttonHandler is further connected to a function which simply takes the text written in box and make it appear down the page as a child element.

Now the problem is, I have no idea how to control the presence of these new child elements. I want to be able to change their color, font, and where on page are they appearing. and if possible, I want them to appear in separate boxes.

[image: pic]

```
[coding][2]
```

Comment: Why so much theory? share your code and keep your question short and on the point

Comment: Please provide the code you have used, preferably inserted into a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: You should read more about the DOM before asking that kind of questions, there is too much to explain for a simple question here (becoming off-topic, in my opinion)

Comment: Please provide the code you had done so far

Comment: coding: http://jsfiddle.net/pyari/E6Nns/ @JanneKlouman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed your jsFiddle a bit to demo the following http://jsfiddle.net/Klors/E6Nns/5/

Once you have your

```
var li =document.createElement("li");
li.innerHTML = msg;
```

you can start to manipulate styles by either giving them a class, some styles, or both. eg.

```
li.style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";
li.style.color = "#000000";
li.style.border = "1px solid pink";
```

or

```
li.className = "heading";
```

As for positioning them all, you need to style your `<div class="list">`, you can do that in the CSS by applying some positioning. (also physically move it outside of `<div class="wrapper">`). eg.

```
div.list {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 20px;
    width: 100px;
}
```